# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'loadVideoById' of null

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, youtube, ionic2

I am not able to play youtube videos in ionic 2. It's showing this ERROR:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'loadVideoById' of null

```
launchPlayer(id): void {
    this.youtube.player.loadVideoById(id);
    this.youtube.videoId = id;
    return this.youtube;
  }
```

When I observe the console, I'm getting the value of id.

Please help.

Comment: Probably `this.youtube.player` is null

Comment: yes it shows null how can i solve it i'm new in ionic 2 pls help

Comment: show the entire controller/component/class typescript

Comment: playVideo(id){
    this.player.launchPlayer(id)
    this.vPlayer = true; 
 
  }            //----------------------  ---------------------  ---------------------  ---------------------  //
  launchPlayer(id): void {
  console.log(this.youtube.player);
    this.youtube.player.loadVideoById(id);
    this.youtube.videoId = id;
    return this.youtube;
  }

Comment: i got the tutorial from this site https://piratesofjs.wordpress.com/2017/02/13/ionic-2-app-tutorial-a-simple-youtube-player/

Comment: Hello @pezetter it was my net work issue i solved it but now i'm getting a new issue    Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of null
TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of null
    at W.g.P (www-widgetapi.js:111)
    at PlayerService.loadPlayer (player.service.ts:37)
    at PlayerService.setupPlayer (player.service.ts:55)
    at new VideoPage (video.ts:24)
    at createClass (core.es5.js:10883)
    at createDirectiveInstance (core.es5.js:10701)
    at createViewNodes (core.es5.js:12064)
    at createRootView (core.es5.js:11969)
    at Object.createProdRootView

Answer (score 1):

I dont know if the problem is solved or not but maybe someone else  need the answer :)

### I got this problem and I saw your question before solving it

---

the problem came from HomePage as your website tutorial

```
 constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,public player: PlayerService,public youtubeService: YoutubeService,public loadingCtrl:LoadingController) {
    player.setupPlayer();
  }
```

remove `player.setupPlayer();` from the constructor and insert this

```
 ionViewDidLoad() {
    this.player.setupPlayer();
  }
```

I hope this will help

Comment: Thanks for the answer i'll try this and let you know